# ValueError: GRU(reset_after=False) is not compatible with GRU(reset_after=True)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

How to solve this error which is raised when loading the weights from h5 file?

> ValueError: GRU(reset_after=False) is not compatible with
> GRU(reset_after=True)

Github link : https://github.com/emilwallner/Screenshot-to-code
Colab link  : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/106_QEi_Wp6mfDDE1E2lPSPh7S9CABk6B#revisionId=0Byh7i7xj0YHlMU0xaTJCWDA3ZzZNTlA1VFFRWU5xQWdtc2tFPQ

dataset drive link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BTeUbXO7qBvOT4VkhOrr7SOcSocSZyeb?usp=sharing

Comment: We should use tools like figma that will automatically convert design to code.

Answer (score 2):

set `reset_after=True` in your GRU layer

Answer (score 0):

Probably the version of the TensorFlow is not compatible with other packages. Try using Tensorflow==1.15.0. You can install it by writing `pip install TensorFlow==1.15.0`